# How to solve Layout issues with nested StackViews?

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I am getting a few layout issues while taking a 3-D view of the UI designed.

So this is the View where there is one Vertical StackView and within it a list of stackView.
Ex-

[image]

As you can see in the above image there are 4 internal stack views and here are the constraints for all the elements within it.

[image]

Everything looks good on UI but when I take a 3-D view of above I am getting layout issues.
Though I can understand giving the constant stackView height to all will fix it but as the text is dynamic I can't have a constant height.

[image]

Comment: why you are setting height of labels?

Comment: remove all heights .. and you are ready to go

Comment: Hey @jawadAli, Even after removing the individual height of the labels it shows this layout issue. It says height is ambiguous  for the main view i.e HorizontalStackView

Comment: what is the fill mode ?

Comment: For all the stack view it is "Scale to Fill"

Comment: stack view have option ? scale to fill ? strange for me

Comment: Sorry, I thought you are asking contentMode.  By the way, the Distribution and Alignment both are "fill"

Comment: make it fill propotionally

Comment: @Let's_Create - be a little more detailed in your question. Is your image showing 4 rows from a table view? Or 4 cells from a collection view? Or is this in a scroll view? You also haven't shown any information about how your Horizontal stack view is constrained.

Comment: @Let's_Create (and @jawadAli) ... by the way, don't bother trying Fill Proportionally on your stack views. That won't have anything to do with the constraint errors, and will almost certainly (definitely) not give you the layout you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a layout that does ***not*** generate any layout warnings / ambiguities:

[image]

The stack views' properties are set as follows:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I designed one "Row Stack" in the Vertical "Outer Stack" and then just duplicated it 3 times.

Here is how it looks at run-time (labels have background colors to make it easy to see their frames):

[image]

and with the label backgrounds set to clear:

[image]

Comment: thanks for taking the time for this detailed answer It solved my issue.